# Don't know how to show custom taxonomies from a custom post_type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, child-theme

I created a custom post_type called Events, where I can show the Events(`URL:HTTP://localhost.com/events`) that are load by the archive-events.php that I created.

Now I have created a custom taxonomy called counties that I want to use to filter Events by the county in which they are located. I'm able to apply counties to specific Events, but I have no idea how to show them. I have tried to create a taxonomy-counties.php

But I have no idea how to test it or debug it since if I try to go to `HTTP://localhost.com/events/county` or `HTTP://localhost.com/county` it takes me to a '404 Page Not Found'.

This is the code that I used to create the taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'create_counties_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0);

function create_counties_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Counties', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'County', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Counties' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Counties' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent County' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent County:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit County' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update County' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New County' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New County Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Counties' ),
    );
    
    // Register Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('counties',array('events'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'county' ),
  ));
}
```

I have tried going through the WordPress developer documentation but unfortunately haven't been able to understand this and found an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to show? Do you want to show list of counties and after that it will list of events associate with that?

Comment: Yeah, my idea was for the user to be able to select a county and to display all the Events in that county

Comment: To display counties in a template you need to use get_terms() of WP and by iterating the each county/terms you can get specific county URL by calling get_term_link() function of WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did work for you:

First, I registered custom post type and taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');
add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin_init');

function my_admin_init() {
    $role = get_role( 'administrator' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_event' );
  $role->add_cap( 'read_event' );
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_event' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'read_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'publish_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'read_private_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_private_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_private_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'create_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_events' );
  $role->add_cap( 'delete_others_event' );
}
function my_init() {
    global $post;
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __( 'event', 'webto' ),
        'singular_name'       => __( 'Header component', 'webto' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Event', 'webto' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parental:', 'webto' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'event', 'webto' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View', 'webto' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add new event', 'webto' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add new', 'webto' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit event', 'webto' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update event ', 'webto' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Find event', 'webto' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'webto' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in the bin', 'webto' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array('title'),
        'public'              => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'capability_type' => array('event', 'events'),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'events' ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position'       => 1,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
    );
    register_post_type( 'events', $args );

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'county', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'county', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search county' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All counties' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent county' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent county:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit county' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update county' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New county' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New county Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'counties' )
    );

    // Register Taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('county', array('events'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public'        => true,
        'publicly_queryable'        => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    ));
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

I got the following:

[image]

Create your posts and assign counties to them

[image]

The countieson the counties page will have links to view

We can create an archive page for specific counties

**taxonomy-county.php**

Also display yours posts

```
// templates/your-template/taxonomy-county.php
<?php
global $post;
$county = get_queried_object();


$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'events',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $county->taxonomy,
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => $county->term_id
    )
  )
);
// Get posts by current county
$events = get_posts($args);

// All counties
$all_counties = get_terms($county->taxonomy);

foreach($all_counties as $county) {
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'events',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $county->taxonomy,
          'field' => 'term_id',
          'terms' => $county->term_id
        )
      )
    );
    // get posts by county
    $events = get_posts($args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to found the solution to my problem. I don't know exactly why but I had to reset the permalinks and it worked.